# How to use SimpleBar with Livewire?

Tags: laravel, alpine-linux, laravel-livewire, simplebar

When using SimpleBar with livewire, at first render it works just fine but after calling any method it stops working but the elements of SimpleBar stay there so I cannot initialize it again like this:

```
document.addEventListener("livewire:load", () => {
    Livewire.hook('message.processed', () => {
        new SimpleBar(document.getElementById('simplebar'));
    });
});
```

I am using alpine to initialize SimpleBar like this:

```
<ul x-data x-init="new SimpleBar($root)" id="simplebar">
...
</ul>
```

does anyone have experience with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I've fixed in the following way:

```
<div id="myElement">
 {{ $slot }}
</div>

<script>
var myElement = document.getElementById('screenshot');
var simple = new SimpleBar(myElement, { autoHide:true });
</script>
```

You need to create a laravel component like above. Next, wrap all content that needs to be rendered with livewire.

```
<x-my-laravel-component>
@livewire('mylivewirecomponent')
</x-my-laravel-component>
```

By this way the livewire component is encapsuled and it can be rendered multiple times, i've trying with livewire events and other ways, but i can't found other solution. I hope that it's useful